# Could the forces that hold the galaxies together already have changed?

Tags: gravity

Since the theory is, that effect of gravity travels at the speed of light, could the forces that hold galaxies together already have changed as we are 20k light years are so away from the centre ? And this could be true for all galaxies ?

Comment: Also the Sun could have disappeared in a puff of smoke 2 minutes ago and we wouldn't know yet.

Comment: But we would in 2 minutes but the question is whether the galaxy and other objects are still place

Comment: Where is the principal difference?